# "As years pass" or "as the years pass"?

Tags: articles

Tell me please if I need to use *the* in the sentences below.

> As (**the**) years pass, white dwarfs cool down and begin to dim.
>
> As (**the**) years pass, Kate begins to become more reserved.

Actually the first sentence was used with *the* by a native english speaker, but I do not undestand why it was used. As for the second one I am not sure whether I need to use *the* or not. Does the phrase *as*  *years* *pass* always have to be used with *the*, If yes, then why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The is an article adjective. It implies a specific set of years. You could say

> As years pass, white dwarfs cool down and begin to dim.

and be just as grammatically correct. But let's say in context it was phrased like this:

> White dwarfs take several million year to implode. As the years pass, they cool down and begin to dim.

In this context, "the years" refers to the several million in the previous sentence. 
As I mentioned though, both the first and the second sentences you quoted are perfectly grammatically correct, but I find that "the years" is more commonly used.

Comment: Can we omit **the** here? "White dwarfs take several million year to implode. As years pass, they cool down and begin to dim."

Comment: Yes, **the** can be omitted here. It sounds more flowing to using "the years" in this context, just from my experience.